# In android Eclipse - I'm unable to upload new screen(layout) at the moment the progress bar finished

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, progress-bar

The Error that I receive is "Unfortunately XXXXXX has stopped".Probably something wrong in the onContinue function.

When the progress bar finished it's upload I want him to view the next layout MainScreen.class

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
protected static final int TIMER_RUNTIME = 10000; // in ms --> 10s

protected boolean mbActive;
protected ProgressBar mProgressBar;
@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.apploading);
  mProgressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.adprogress_progressBar);

  final Thread timerThread = new Thread() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
          mbActive = true;
          try {
              int waited = 0;
              while(mbActive && (waited < TIMER_RUNTIME)) {
                  sleep(200);
                  if(mbActive) {
                      waited += 200;
                      updateProgress(waited);
                  }
              }
      } catch(InterruptedException e) {
          // do nothing
      } finally {
          onContinue();
      }
    }
 };
 timerThread.start();
 }

 @Override
 public void onDestroy() {
   super.onDestroy();
 }
 public void updateProgress(final int timePassed) {
   if(null != mProgressBar) {
       // Ignore rounding error here
       final int progress = mProgressBar.getMax() * timePassed / TIMER_RUNTIME;
       mProgressBar.setProgress(progress);
   }
 }

 public void onContinue() {
 // Moved to the Application to the Main Screen
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainScreen.class);
   startActivity(intent);  

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are sleeping in the UI thread, which will cause an ANR. I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do but if you wish to execute long-running tasks have a look at [Asynctask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or a [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

Also have a read here on keeping your application responsive and avoiding ANRS. [Keeping Your App Responsive](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html#Avoiding)

> Android applications normally run entirely on a single thread by default the "UI thread" or "main thread"). This means anything your application is doing in the UI thread that takes a long time to complete can trigger the ANR dialog because your application is not giving itself a chance to handle the input event or intent broadcasts.
>
> Therefore, any method that runs in the UI thread should do as little work as possible on that thread. In particular, activities should do as little as possible to set up in key life-cycle methods such as onCreate() and onResume(). Potentially long running operations such as network or database operations, or computationally expensive calculations such as resizing bitmaps should be done in a worker thread (or in the case of databases operations, via an asynchronous request).

Answer (score 0):

```
updateProgress(waited);
```

can not be executed on your timerThread. All the operations that modify the UI have to be executed on the UI Thread. Use an Handler or runOnTheUiThread

```
final finalWaited = waited;
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               updateProgress(finalWaited);   
            }
        });
```